# How to remove renderers from a plot?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I'm experimenting with Bokeh server. I have a document with three figures and I'm trying to update two of them depending on the selection I perform on the third. The number of lines to plot in the two figures changes every time.

If I could use multi_line, this would be trivial: I would change the xs and ys in the data_source of the multi_line. 
Alas, I need to use multiple scatter plots because multi_line does not support hover and I need it.

So, what I would like to accomplish is to clear the two plots every time I select something in the third, and display the scatter plots corresponding to the new selection.

There are a few possible workarounds, of course (appending scatter points to have a single GlyphRenderer with all scatter plots together, for example, but this would mean using very clunky ways to send the right hover message...). But if it was possible to just clear and update single figures, everything would be cleaner. I couldn't find anything in the docs, however.

Comment: We definitely optimized around the use-case of updating data for existing renderers. I think changing renderers should work just fine, but I expect it its kind of clunky to do. You might stop by the Bokeh public mailing list with more details, example code, etc. SO is not good for iterative / discursive help (SO folks yell at you for giving "not-answers")

Comment: I will never yell at someone who spends some time to give help, even if just by saying "ask elsewhere, this is not the right place" :). So, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have read [the thread you created on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/bokeh/remove$20renderers$20from$20plots/bokeh/1ovbaXFOtSw/2JoGG7oLAwAJ) and this [**other thread**](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/bokeh/remove$20renderers$20from$20plots/bokeh/TR8qXwokG34/_BfE1ARKBgAJ) where Bryan says:

> Technically, glyph renderers are stored in the `.renderers` property of
>   Plots, but **I would not recommend rooting around there by hand**.
>   Specifically the "Continuous Updating" notebook I linked earlier has
>   an example of updating both the data and appearance of an existing
>   glyph using python and push_notebook. There is not any easy way to remove glyphs at the moment,
>   other options would be:
>
> - recreate a new plot
> - set the glyph to be invisble
> - update the glyphs data

So it seems they are the only solutions at the moment